# @DirtiesContext for Quarkus

Tags: spring-boot, quarkus, quarkus-panache

Is there something like @DirtiesContext in Quarkus that allows me to drop the database tables before each test case is executed?

There is the `hibernate-orm.database.generation` that can be set to drop-and-create but it doesn't quite do the same thing as @DirtiesContext.